# Saving a type into a variable and create new instances using it

Tags: java, oop, structure

A bit about my system:

I am making a RPG game and I want people to select a kit. A kit is like a class which has it's own effects and items.

Now each player can select a kit using a command.

Each kit implements the Kit interface:

```
public interface Kit {

    public void addItems();
    public void execute();

}
```

Example of a kit class:

```
public class Warrior implements Kit {

    private Client player;

    public Warrior(Client c) {
        this.player = c;
    }

    /**
     * Adds item to the player.
     */

    @Override
    public void addItems() {
        for (Integer item : PlayerKits.WARRIOR.getItems()) {
            this.player.getItems().addItem(item, 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is used for kits effects.
     */

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // TODO add a task scheduler and handle kit effects
    }

}
```

Now in the Client object, I have this:

```
public Kit playerKit = null;
```

My problem:

In case that the player did NOT select a kit, the system will use the default kit.
I want to store the default kit type into a final variable so the system dynamically will use the default kit type as instance.

***Not compilable*** example:

```
private final Kit DEFAULT_KIT = Warrior;

public void setKit(Client c) {
    if (c.playerKit != null) {
        c.playerKit.addItems();
        c.playerKit.execute();
    } else {
        c.playerKit = new DEFAULT_KIT();
        c.playerKit.addItems();
        c.playerKit.execute();          
    }
}
```

This is basically shows the idea I want to implement but I don't think it is possible to store types into a variable and then create a new instance using them.

Of course I can do this:

```
private final PlayerKits DEFAULT_KIT = PlayerKits.WARRIOR;

public void getType() {
    switch(DEFAULT_KIT) {
        case WARRIOR:
            return new Warrior();
            break;
        // ... more cases
    }
}
```

But I want the solution to be short, simple, and a good design.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: Dependency injection using `Spring` would work very nicely here.

Comment: What's the problem with `c.playerKit = new Warrior();` or with `public Kit playerKit = new Warrior();`? Also, you should revise your design: fields should not be public, and having cyclic reference from client to kit and from kit to client is often a bad idea. Finally, all upper-case is for constants: *static* final fields.

Comment: @JBNizet I want it to be dynamic so I only need to change the type in one place. What if tomorrow I want to create multiple RPGs arenas or more similar games with same purpose or do the same thing in another place? I would only need to change the type and done. And I know I was just using examples, didnt want to create getters for the example. About the finals, thank you, I didn't know that

Comment: `Kit playerKit = new Warrior();` initializes all instances of Client with a Kit which is a Warrior by default. It's in a single place, and there's not repetition. If you have other kinds of objects than Clients who also need a default kit, of the same type as clients, then use `Kit kit = Kits.createDefaultKit();` everywhere a default kit is needed. The choice of the default kit would thus be encapsulated inside the `Kits.createDefaultKit()`method, used everywhere a default kit is needed.

Comment: @JBNizet I see where are you getting, I will do it that way if I won't get an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Type in Java is represented as a class in runtime. References to classes can be stored in variables like this:

```
private final Class<Kit> DEFAULT_KIT = Warrior.class;

  public void setKit(Client c) {
    ...
    c.playerKit = DEFAULT_KIT.newItem();
    ...
  }
}
```